# rich-text editor for message body in Hotmail freezes when entering subject and Addressee first

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome, richtextbox, hotmail, windows-live

It's a strange problem, happened hundred of times.
I am trying to find out why is the rich-text editor for message body in Hotmail Freezes when you enter subject and Addressee first.(some times!).

I am using The Latest Version of Chrome Version 22.0.1229.94 m.
I think it's related to Silverlight, Have anyone experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated to Outlook, it's much better now, and this problem is not there anymore